# SAPUI5 fill whole MatrixLayoutCell with button

Tags: matrix, layout, sapui5

I want to fill a whole MatrixLayoutCell with a button, so that it covers the cell completely.
[image: Right now it looks like this]

The button height is increased with a CSS class, but the layout cuts it off.
The dark blue part is the cell where the button is located. So the cell accepts the heigth.

My CSS code:

```
.myProductButton .sapMBtnInner{

      background-color: #0080ff !important;

      border-color: #0000a0!important;

      background-image: none !important;

      text-shadow: none !important;

      font-weight: bold !important;

      height: 200px!important;

}
```

A code snippet from my view:

```
        var row1 = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayoutRow("row_1");
var cell1 = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayoutCell("cell_1");
cell1.addContent(prod1);
cell1.setBackgroundDesign('Fill1');

row1.addCell(cell1);
row1.setHeight('200px');

matrix_cell1.addRow(row1);

prod_cell1.addContent(matrix_cell1);
```

I tried several things but didn't work.
Someone got an idea how to solve this in MatrixLayout, or do I need to change the layout to Grid?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @nistv4n said you can set the width of the button to 100% and remove the cell padding with `padding:"None"`.

To adjust the height you can add a style class to the button (as you probably have already done):

```js
prod1.addStyleClass("myProductButton");
```

and use a hand full of css to expand the height and vertically align the text:

```css
.myProductButton{
  height:200px;
  padding:0;
}
.myProductButton .sapMBtnInner{
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.myProductButton .sapMBtnInner .sapMBtnContent{
  width:100%
}
```

Example on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ciyuzuniqe/1/edit?html,js,output).

But please note that it is not recommended and [not officially supported](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/36/3cd16eba1f45babe3f661f321a7820/content.htm) to use sap.m and sap.ui.commons in the same application.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `width` property of the button to 100% to fit the container.
If you set `padding="None"` to the cell, no space will present at the end of the cell.

Example:

```
<layout:MatrixLayoutCell backgroundDesign="Fill1" padding="None">
   <Button text="Test Button" width="100%"/>
</layout:MatrixLayoutCell>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nistv4n/93mx0yvt/) (with an XML view but the properties are the same, you need to call `setPadding()` and `setWidth()` correspondingly.

With regard to the height of the button: currently it's not possible to stretch the button's height in MatrixLayout. Furthermore, I do not recommend to change the height of a button - it has standardized responsive height.